# latex draw- mathematical letters and symbols

Tags: labels

When I am using Linux mint 17  i found this mistake rather not in windows. That is, in this Linux i have put Latex Draw 2.0 it is not giving the mathematical symbols. that is, Suppose i wish to name a corner of a rectangle as $\beta$ it is giving as it in the commands.

[image: note down the left top corner]

Kindly help me to do the correction.. Or suggest me some other drawing software like latexDraw which will generate the latex command by its own..

I am adding one more pic for ur assistance...

![my working on latex Draw..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mOur.png)

Comment: The [manual](https://github.com/arnobl/latexdraw/wiki/Manual#latex-text-rendering) of LaTeXDraw discusses some cases, when the text is not successfully rendered by LaTeX (error, LaTeX not installed, ...).

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of: [Typing errors in LaTeX Draw](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185751/5764)

Answer (score 1):

One way, with [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1.5,0) rectangle (0,1.5) node[above right] {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course.. i know and i am using tikz...But for an urgent we need to use latex draw which helps to draw very fast... comparatively.. thats why..

Comment: OK, it is of course up to you to select which option is best for you. But your question did ask for alternatives to LaTeXDraw, which is what I've provided here.

Comment: ya ofcourse... but i need a package which will generate their own codes like latexDraw. thanks for ur commands.. What ur command about geogebra...

Comment: You can use `IPE` too.